What's this (very) indie movie were the protagonist always looks 20?
I've been trying to  find this movie I saw about one year ago.
It's a very short (around 50 minutes to an hour) independent movie.
It's about a guy's life. About how he ran into his girlfriend cheating on him in the beginning, how he had a crappy job at some restaurant, how he managed to have a wife and a family, how he kinda threw it away for an adventure with the maid. I also think he hated his father... not sure. Anyway, it's basically about his life from the cheating to...

 his death (heart attack).

One very specific thing I remember about this movie though is that although years pass, the protagonist keep the very same 20 years old look, doesn't matter how old he was.

 Even on the time of his death (he was like 70-80 maybe) he's still being played by the same 20 years old actor with not even the slightest makeup modification.

So I hope someone will help, I'm pretty desperate. Really.

The fact that he didn't age was not part of the plot line. It was more like an artistic choice. I sadly can't remember any dialog.
I mostly remember the overall impression the protagonist left me. He was kind of slim, average height, brown-dark hair. He was not showing emotion although he was verbally expressing them.
When I try to picture him more precisely I end up seeing  Kieran Culkin.
I watched this online.
